# Can't install Python math library in Docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I am building a docker image. I have this command in Dockerfile -

> pip3 install -r requirements.txt

The contents of the requirement.txt are -

- pybind11
- cppimport
- jupyter
- numpy
- pandas
- scikit-learn
- math
- random

Everything installs as it should other than "math". When Installing math following error message occurs -

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement math (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for math (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))

How can I solve this and install math?

Comment: there is indeed no math library on [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=math)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`math`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html) is a built in library for python. You don't need to install it. Just remove it from `requirements.txt`.

If you are having a similar problem importing other Python modules in a Docker image using the `requirements.txt` file, make sure it is not one of Python's many, many other [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html). The complete list is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html):
https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html

(Select the appropriate version from the dropdown menu at the top of the [page](https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html).)

Comment: same for `random`

Answer (score 2):

[`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), along with Python's many, many other [built-in modules](https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html), should not be included in the `requirements.txt` file. Delete that line from the file.

The complete list of built-in modules (i.e. modules which shouldn't be in `requirements.txt`) is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html):
https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html

(Be sure to select your Python version from the dropdown menu at the top of the [page](https://docs.python.org/3.8/py-modindex.html).)

This post applies when creating a Docker image, such as with Binder from a GitHub repository. It does not apply when importing modules in a Python script.